# PIXEL WARS - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function have_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently I purchased a wordpress theme but unfortunately, I cannot upload it on my localhost due to this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function have_posts() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cosmic\index.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cosmic\index.php on line 26

Below is the code for my index.php file

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['layout']))
    {
        if ($_GET['layout'] == 'grid')
        {
            get_template_part('layout', 'grid');
        }
        elseif ($_GET['layout'] == 'list')
        {
            get_template_part('layout', 'list');
        }
        elseif ($_GET['layout'] == 'circles')
        {
            get_template_part('layout', 'circles');
        }
        else
        {
            get_template_part('layout', 'regular');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $layout = 'Regular';
        
        if (! have_posts())
        {
            $layout = 'Regular';
        }
        else
        {
            $layout = efor_archive_layout();
        }
        
        if (($layout == 'Grid') || ($layout == '1st Full + Grid'))
        {
            get_template_part('layout', 'grid');
        }
        elseif (($layout == 'List') || ($layout == '1st Full + List'))
        {
            get_template_part('layout', 'list');
        }
        elseif ($layout == 'Circles')
        {
            get_template_part('layout', 'circles');
        }
        else
        {
            get_template_part('layout', 'regular');
        }
    }

?>
```

How to sort this error out?

Comment: Hae you tried reaching out to the developer of the theme yet? If not then that's something you should try (especially since you paid for the theme and all).

Comment: ... although from the error message it seems you didn't install the theme correctly. Your `\htdocs\cosmic\index.php` shouldn't contain the code you shared. Did you accidentally replace WordPress' index.php file with the one from the theme?

Comment: Hi, Thankyou for you response. I have re-confirmed the index.php in the htdocs - cosmic folder. It is exactly the same as extracted from the theme when bought...

Comment: I have also tried contacting the Developer almost over a week ago but no response as yet from him/her